# Weird behavior of Google chrome

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome

I've installed Google chrome on my new Windows 8. When I load some sites their behavior differs a little bit from that I have on Gooogle chrome on my windows xp machine. For example,

1. **translate.google.com**
       This one has a feature called instant translate(translation occurs when you're typing). It doesn't work.     I've opened chrome
   developer tools to figure out the problems. There was one. It sais
   that chrome failed yo load resource [desktop_module_async.js](https://translate.google.com/translate/releases/twsfe_w_20130916_RC01/r/js/desktop_module_async.js)
   resource. As I understand that js file performs instant translating
2. **youtube**:   when I open youtube the page renders, but all videos don't
   get played(also all preview pictures for videos don't get
       loaded). In Chrome console I see a lot of errors indicating
       `Uncaught SyntaxError:Unexpected identifier`
3. **Google+** when open the google+ I get the error page indicating that there were some problems during loading CSS
4. **Google maps** Simply see the blank page and in the console: Failed to load resource maps.google.com

I have `29.0.1547.66 m` version of chrome. On xp machine it is `29.0.1547.76 m` version. When I try to update the version of Chrome on windows 8 machine I get error 7 complaining that downloded file has not passed the verification.

Have you any ideas what can cause such problems?
P.S. On my windows xp machine there are no such problems

**EDIT 1**
Seems the problem relates to browser cache. Google sends different respones based on the version of operating system. I've found similar topic on superuser. When I cleared my cache everything works fine. Thanks to all

**EDIT 2**
No, cache doesn't cause such behavior. I cleared the cache, worked for some time, then reboot my laptop, opened Chrome and saw this again. Then I tried to clear all cache for all period, but it didn't help.

**EDIT 3**
Seems that this issue is not unique https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390134/failed-to-load-resource-under-chrome

In my case its not the Adblock extension because I have completely remove it. Also I have a wired connection, so it's not a hardware problem

So the question is still open!

Comment: Do you have the most recent versions of Java (32 **and** 64 bit) & Flash? It usually causes this kind of problems.

Comment: Adobe flash player site says that I have flash player already built into my Chrome. How do the described problems refer to java?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, got a little confused. Java isn't related to this issue. Also, try to re-download Chrome to update it, not via the `about` window. It will take extra couple of minutes but Google syncs everything so it isn't that bad.

Comment: @maks What happens if you disable the build-in flash plugin under `chrome://plugins/` and use the normal installed flash plugin instead? Does it solve the youtube problem?

Comment: @nixda and how to say chrome to use the normal one?

Comment: I think the problem is not in flash player. As I said these problems apperarsnot only on youtube. Maybe it some kind of connection problems of my windows 8?

Comment: @maks Click on [details](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/enable-system-flash-player-google-chrome.html) to see two flash plugins. Disable the one where "out-of-process" stands. Easy to miss :)

Comment: @maks make that as an answer of your edit and accept it, it will be helpful to others users in future.

Comment: Maybe there are harmful plugins installed. Disable all plugins and restart Chrome.

Comment: I've disabled all plugins, but it didn't help

Comment: Have you tried opening `desktop_module_async.js` manually (entering it in the Omnibox)? What happens if you do?

Comment: I see the js code of that file

Comment: So it’s not security software blocking it. You’ve tried disabling plugins, but what about extensions?

Comment: and also extensions are disabled

Comment: Do you happen to have Privoxy installed?

Comment: No, I don't know what it is.